# Open cv compare two face embeddings

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I went through [Pyimagesearch face Recognition tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/),
but my application need to compare two faces only,
I have embedding of two faces, how to compare them using opencv ?
about the trained model which is use to extract embedding from face is mentioned in link,
I want to know that what methods I should try to compare two face embedding.

(Note: I am new to this field)

Comment: That tutorial is not a short one, at which step you are stuck?

Comment: I would say, in this field, there is usually not a "best" method. You should try different methods and figure out which one works better for you.

Comment: @unlut I stuck on a face recognition part, in this tutorial they already have data-set of know faces and they compare new face with their own data-set, i just want to compare two unknown faces, where I want to detect that they are same or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the article you mentioned, you can actually compare if two faces are the same using only the [face_recognition library](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition).

You can use the [compare faces](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#identify-faces-in-pictures) to determine if two pictures have the same face

```
import face_recognition
known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")

biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding], unknown_encoding)
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all your case is similar to given tutorial, instead of multiple images you have single image that you need to compare with test image,

So you don't really need training step here.

You can do

```
# read 1st image and store encodings
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb, model=args["detection_method"])
encodings1 = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)

# read 2nd image and store encodings
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb, model=args["detection_method"])
encodings2 = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb, boxes)


# now you can compare two encodings
# optionally you can pass threshold, by default it is 0.6
matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encoding1, encoding2)
```

`matches` will give you `True` or `False` based on your images

Comment: thank you for your feedback, i am already using this method but it is taking 3-4 sec for complete process and i want to cut down time to 1-1.5 sec, for that i found open-face model takes less time to make encodings but then for comparing embedding generated by open-face model are not giving accurate results, so I am trying to find other ways to compare them

Comment: before moving to other model try playing with `tolerance` in `compare_faces`. You need to find optimal value for your case. Default value is `0.6`. Try changing it to `0.5` or less